# Building a Doughnut Chart on Google API - Pie inside a Pie

Tags: api, charts

I have been trying to build a doughnut chart that is compatible with WIX. I need the chart to be somewhat interactive, at least mouse-over effects are necessary.

Since Google API does not have doughnut charts. I made two pie charts with the goal of fitting the smaller one inside the other. I also used the pieHole option to create a hole inside each of the pies.

After I figured out how to position two divs on top of each other I am now struggling with the problem shown in the picture. The div that contains the smaller pie is covering the div with the bigger pie. How can I make the div's background transparent while keeping the content (the smaller pie) solid?

Any ideas are welcome. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pieHole option, setting it to something between 0 and 1. [Api docs with example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the Google Chart API has a donut chart option... [This bihappy post](http://bihappyblog.com/2012/03/29/google-visualization-donut-chart/) demonstrates how you can cheat it though, by placing a circle layer over the top of a pie chart:

In your head...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
       data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
       data.addRows([
       ['A',    roundNumber(11*Math.random(),2)],
       ['B',      roundNumber(2*Math.random(),2)],
       ['C',  roundNumber(2*Math.random(),2)],
       ['D', roundNumber(2*Math.random(),2)],
       ['E',    roundNumber(7*Math.random(),2)]
       ]);
var options = {
width: 450, height: 300,
colors:['#ECD078','#D95B43','#C02942','#542437','#53777A'],
legend: {position: 'none'},
   animation:{
       duration: 800,
       easing: 'in'
     }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
function roundNumber(num, dec) {
 var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
 return result;
}
</script>
```

In your body...

```
<div id="link_div" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; left: 180px; top: 30px;">
<a href="javascript:drawChart()">Change Data</a>

<div id="chart_div" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 20px;"></div>
<div id="circle_div" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; left: 180px; top: 127px;">
<img src="circle.png"></div>
```